# How do I create a GIT repository in XCode using VSO?

Tags: xcode, git, azure-devops

I have an existing project in XCode 8.  I have also created a project in VSO at 'myproject'.visualstudio.com.

In Xcode preferences I set up two accounts.  One is my Apple ID account, the other is for the VSO Account - but that is the one giving me trouble.  I pasted the URL that VSO provides in the code section when no code has yet been pushed into the settings - set it for user name and password and entered my user name and password.  But XCode repeatedly tells me authentication failed.  Tried my username@gmail.com or just username and password - double checked on the password - could not get it to work.  Since I'm the only one in the VSO team project, I tried adding another user and used that for the credentials, but no luck.  Not sure if I am missing something or if XCode 8 and VSO are simply not compatible.  Any input or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter VSO credentials in xcode, enter VSO username for **User Name**, and enter PAT for **Password**.

More detail steps, please refer [share your code in git xcode](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode).